# How to use same telethon client with same session many times

Tags: python, asynchronous, client, python-asyncio, telethon

I have this Telethon code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio

api_id = ""
api_hash = ""
session = "john"
username = 'Hello_World'   # For Example

async def main():
    client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()

    entity = await client.get_entity("https://t.me/ahsan_alhadeeth")
    search_user = await client.get_participants(entity, search=username)

    print(search_user)

def in_channel():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

in_channel()
in_channel()
```

when I use a single call to `in_channel()` it runs normally until finish.

But when using two calls it returns an error : `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`.

I want to know how to use same client many times without making multiple sessions.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to do the same task multiple times, at the SAME time. Since this is asyncio functions, you would want to wait on the first in_channel() to finish, before the next in_channel is executed. the database() is probably locked because the client is already in used.

When you say use the same client many times, do you mean, run in_channel() multiple times untill it is complete, or is your goal to run in_channel() many times simultaniously?

I could probably help you, but i would need more answers :-)

(sorry this is a 'Answer'. im not allowed to make a comment untill i have 50 points.)

Answer (score 0):

Better you can make a loop of the same session but add a `client.disconnect()` in the end of main function.

Comment: Could you also provide an explanation of why it is better? It would make your answer better as it will be easier to understand why it is better.

Answer (score 0):

`client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)`

TelegramClient creates a session with Telegram and represents your bot or client communication with Telegram. Just to ensure, this is not your session with any particular user ( for ex: John). You can interact with any no of users, you want, subject to someone having initiated a conversation with you or your user/bot associated with credentials (api_id, api_hash) being added to the respective channel/ group.
You should think of this client as one connection where multiple instances can be created to load balance multiple calls.

Your code can be fixed as below:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio

class TClient:
    def __init__(self, session):
        api_id = ""
        api_hash = ""
        self.session = session

    async def init(self, username = 'Hello_World'):
        self.client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
        await self.client.start()

    async def main(self):
        entity = await client.get_entity("https://t.me/ahsan_alhadeeth")
        search_user = await client.get_participants(entity, search=username)

        print(search_user)

    def in_channel(self, callFn, args):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(callFn(args))

    in_channel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc1 = TClient(session = "john1")
    tc1.in_channel(tc.init())
    tc1.in_channel(tc.main(username = 'Hello_World'))
    tc1.in_channel(tc.main(username = 'Hello_World2'))

    tc2 = TClient(session = "bot2")
    tc2.in_channel(tc.init(username = 'Hello_World'))))
    tc2.in_channel(tc.main(username = 'Hello_World2'))
```

The above enables you to reuse your session for multiple users. I made 2 modifications to the above.

1. I have refactored the code so that multiple connections can be created with Telegram clients with different session ids.
2. main function can be call multiple times for various usernames

PS - I haven't tested the above code.

Answer (score 0):

For me , ISP had blocked telegram. So had to use VPN